# PDE system with variables of different dimensions - Porous electrode theory with FiPy

Tags: python-3.x, physics, pde, chemistry, fipy

I'm trying to solve a system of four PDEs describing steady-state [charge conservation in a porous electrode](https://doi.org/10.1002/aic.690210103). The equations are

1. ∇ ⋅<sub>1</sub> + ∇ ⋅ <sub>2</sub> = 0,
2. <sub>1</sub> = − ∇<sub>1</sub>,
3. <sub>2</sub> = − ∇<sub>2</sub>,
4. ∇ ⋅ <sub>1</sub> = <sub>rxn</sub>, or alternatively ∇ ⋅ <sub>2</sub> = -<sub>rxn</sub>.

I want to use FiPy to solve these equations as a set of coupled PDEs on a 1D grid.

```
import fipy.tools.numerix as nrx
from fipy import Grid1D, CellVariable, PowerLawConvectionTerm, DiffusionTerm, Matplotlib1DViewer


## SYSTEM PARAMETERS AND CONSTANTS

cd = 4        # operating current density, A/cm2
T = 333       # operating temperature, K
L = 10*1e-4   # electrode thickness, cm
iEx = 1e-2    # exchange current density, A/cm2
Er = 0        # reaction activation energy, V
nr = 4        # number of electrons in reaction
F = 96485     # faraday's constant, C/mol
R = 8.3145    # molar gas constant, J/Kmol


## NUMERICAL PARAMETERS

nx = 100                          # number of mesh points
dx = L/nx                         # distance between mesh points
mesh = Grid1D(nx = nx, dx = dx)   # 1D grid of length L
tol = 1e-3                        # tolerance for residual
itmax = 100                       # max no. of sweeps to break convergence loop


## PDE VARIABLES AND COEFFICIENTS

irxn = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value = iEx, name = r'$i_\mathrm{rxn}$')  # reaction current density (i_rxn), A/cm2

sigma = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value = 50, name = r'$\sigma$')       # electron conductivity, S/cm
kappa = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value = 100e-3, name = r'$\kappa$')   # proton conductivity, S/cm

phi1 = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, name = r'$\Phi_1$')   # porous electrode matrix potential, V
phi2 = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, name = r'$\Phi_2$')   # porous electrode electrolyte potential, V
i1 = -sigma*phi1.grad                                  # porous electrode matrix current, A/cm2
i2 = -kappa*phi2.grad                                  # porous electrode electrolyte current, A/cm2
i1.name = r'$i_1$'
i2.name = r'$i_2$'


## BOUNDARY CONDITIONS

phi1.constrain(0, where=mesh.facesLeft)       # matrix potential at x=0
i1.constrain(0, where=mesh.facesRight)        # matrix current at x=L
i2.constrain(0, where=mesh.facesLeft)         # electrolyte current at x=0
i2.constrain(cd, where=mesh.facesRight)       # electrolyte current at x=L


## SOLVE EQUATIONS

def solveEquations():

  # equations

  # charge conservation ∇ ⋅ _1 + ∇ ⋅ _2 = 0 (as ∇ ⋅ [− ∇_1] + ∇ ⋅ [− ∇_2] = 0)
  #chargeConservationEq = (DiffusionTerm(coeff = -sigma, var = phi1) + DiffusionTerm(coeff = -kappa, var = phi2) == 0) - this is commented out for testing but gives a similar error
  chargeConservationEq = (PowerLawConvectionTerm(coeff = (1,), var = i1) + PowerLawConvectionTerm(coeff = (1,), var = i2) == 0)
  

  # matrix potential ∇ ⋅ _1 = _rxn
  matrixPotEq = (PowerLawConvectionTerm((1,), var = i1) == irxn)
        
  # electrolyte potential ∇ ⋅ _2 = -_rxn
  electrolytePotEq = (PowerLawConvectionTerm((1,), var = i2) == -irxn)

  # matrix current _1 = − ∇_1 (divergence taken on both sides)
  matrixCurrentEq = (PowerLawConvectionTerm((1,), var = i1) == DiffusionTerm(coeff = -sigma, var = phi1))

  # electrolyte current _2 = − ∇_2 (divergence taken on both sides)
  electrolyteCurrentEq = (PowerLawConvectionTerm((1,), var = i2) == DiffusionTerm(coeff = -kappa, var = phi2))

  eq = ( chargeConservationEq
    & matrixPotEq
    #& electrolytePotEq
    & matrixCurrentEq
    & electrolyteCurrentEq) 

  res = eq.sweep()
  it = 0

  while ((res > tol) and (it < itmax)):

    # increment
    it += 1

    # solve equations
    res = eq.sweep()


solveEquations()
```

However when I try to run I get the error message: `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 2 has 1 dimension(s)`. The error occurs when `eq.sweep()` is called.

I understand that `sigma`, `kappa`, `irxn`, `phi1` and `phi2` have shape (100,) while `i1` and `i2` have shape (1,100). Is this why I get this error? If so, how do I write the equations in a way that can be solved?

I have also tried to combine the equations to get

∇ ⋅ (− ∇<sub>1</sub>) + ∇ ⋅ (− ∇<sub>2</sub>) = 0 and ∇ ⋅ (− ∇<sub>1</sub>) = i<sub>rxn</sub>

in order to simplify the problem to only two variables. In this case I did not get this error, but I also did not get a stable solution and for some reason charge was not conserved even though the first equation should ensure this - when plotting the currents **i**<sub>1</sub> and **i**<sub>2</sub> their sum was not constant as it should be. The boundary conditions were also less stable as there were boundary conditions on the gradients of <sub>2</sub> on either side, following from eq. 3.

Any help is appreciated!

---

**EDIT:** a new version of the code implementing the suggested changes, with more math details. This code runs without the error originally mentioned, but some new questions/issues have appeared.

A summary of the governing equations boundary conditions that should be implemented.:

1. ∇ ⋅ (− ∇<sub>1</sub>) + ∇ ⋅ (− ∇<sub>2</sub>) = 0,
2. ∇ ⋅ (− ∇<sub>1</sub>) = <sub>rxn</sub>

At x=0

- <sub>1</sub> = 0 at x=0,
- ∇<sub>1</sub> = -I<sub>cell</sub>/ (i.e. <sub>1</sub>=I<sub>cell</sub>)
- ∇<sub>2</sub> = 0 (i.e. <sub>2</sub>=0)

At x=L

- ∇<sub>1</sub> = 0 (i.e. <sub>1</sub>=I<sub>cell</sub>)
- ∇<sub>2</sub> = -I<sub>cell</sub>/ (i.e. <sub>2</sub>=I<sub>cell</sub>)

The results here are closer to what I would expect, but something is still not right

- No matter how low or high I set the exchange current density, nothing seems to happen to the currents i1 and i2. This should not be the case, as a lower magnitude of the exchange current density should mean less generated current at a given overpotential.
- Constraining phi2 to be zero at the x=0 boundary implies that there are no reactions there, as the reaction current <sub>rxn</sub> is defined by the [Butler-Volmer equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butler%E2%80%93Volmer_equation) and is zero if the overpotential is zero. This is however not super important.
- The gradient of <sub>2</sub> does not appear to be zero at x=0 as specified?

```
    from fipy import Grid1D, CellVariable, DiffusionTerm, Matplotlib1DViewer
    
    ## SYSTEM PARAMETERS AND CONSTANTS
    
    cd = 4        # operating current density, A/cm2
    T = 333       # operating temperature, K
    L = 10*1e-4   # electrode thickness, cm
    iEx = 1e-2    # exchange current density, A/cm2
    Er = 0        # reaction activation energy, V
    nr = 4        # number of electrons in reaction
    F = 96485     # faraday's constant, C/mol
    R = 8.3145    # molar gas constant, J/Kmol
    beta = 0.5    # symmetry factor for reaction
    
    
    ## NUMERICAL PARAMETERS
    
    nx = 100                          # number of mesh points
    dx = L/nx                         # distance between mesh points
    mesh = Grid1D(nx = nx, dx = dx)   # 1D grid of length L
    tol = 1e-3                        # tolerance for residual
    itmax = 100                       # max no. of sweeps to break convergence loop
    
    
    ## PDE VARIABLES AND COEFFICIENTS
    
    irxn = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value = iEx, name = r'$i_\mathrm{rxn}$')  # reaction current density (i_rxn), A/cm2
    
    sigma = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value = 50, name = r'$\sigma$')       # electron conductivity, S/cm
    kappa = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, value = 100e-3, name = r'$\kappa$')   # proton conductivity, S/cm
    
    phi1 = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, name = r'$\Phi_1$')   # porous electrode matrix potential, V
    phi2 = CellVariable(mesh = mesh, name = r'$\Phi_2$')   # porous electrode electrolyte potential, V
    
    
    ## BOUNDARY CONDITIONS
    
    phi1.constrain(0, where=mesh.facesLeft)                                       # matrix potential grounded at x=0
    phi2.constrain(0, where=mesh.facesLeft)                                       # electrolyte potential grounded at x=0
    phi1.faceGrad.constrain(-cd/sigma.faceValue[0], where=mesh.facesLeft)         # matrix current at x=0
    phi2.faceGrad.constrain([0], where=mesh.facesLeft)                            # electrolyte current at x=0
    phi1.faceGrad.constrain([0], where=mesh.facesRight)                           # matrix current at x=L
    phi2.faceGrad.constrain([-cd/kappa.faceValue[-1]], where=mesh.facesRight)     # electrolyte current at x=L
    
    
    ## SUPPORTING FUNCTIONS
    
    def rcd(phiM, phiE):
    
      # calculate reaction current density
      # inputs: phiM (potential in solid electron-conducting phase) & phiE (potential in proton-conducting electrolyte)
    
      # overpotential
      overPotential = phiM-phiE-Er
    
      # Butler-Volmer equation for reaction current density
      i = iEx*(nrx.exp((beta*nr*F)/(R*T)*overPotential)-nrx.exp(-((1-beta)*nr*F)/(R*T)*overPotential))
    
      return i
    
    
    ## SOLVE EQUATIONS
    
    def solveEquations():
    
      # equations
    
      # charge conservation ∇ ⋅ _1 + ∇ ⋅ _2 = 0 (as ∇ ⋅ [− ∇_1] + ∇ ⋅ [− ∇_2] = 0)
      chargeConservationEq = (DiffusionTerm(coeff = -sigma, var = phi1) + DiffusionTerm(coeff = -kappa, var = phi2) == 0)
      
      # matrix potential ∇ ⋅ _1 = _rxn
      matrixPotEq = (DiffusionTerm(coeff = -sigma, var = phi1) == irxn)
            
      eq = (matrixPotEq & chargeConservationEq)
    
      res = eq.sweep()
      it = 0
    
      while ((res > tol) and (it < itmax)):
    
        # update value of irxn based on overpotential from previous iteration
        irxn.value = rcd(phi1.value, phi2.value)
    
        # increment
        it += 1
    
        # solve equations
        res = eq.sweep()
    
      print(it,'iterations')
      print('residual',res)
    
    
    def plotPotentials():
    
      viewer = Matplotlib1DViewer(vars = (phi1, phi2), title = r'Potential [V]', legend = 'best')
      viewer.plot()
      input('Press return to continue')
    
    def plotCurrents():
    
      i1 = -sigma.faceValue*phi1.faceGrad                                  # porous electrode matrix current, A/cm2
      i2 = -kappa.faceValue*phi2.faceGrad                                  # porous electrode electrolyte current, A/cm2
      i1.name = r'$i_1$'
      i2.name = r'$i_2$'
    
      x = mesh.faceCenters.value[0]
      plt.figure()
      plt.plot(x,i1.value[0],label=r'$i_1$')
      plt.plot(x,i2.value[0],label=r'$i_2$')
      plt.legend(loc = 'best')
      plt.show()
    
    
    solveEquations()
    
    ## UNCOMMENT TO PLOT RESULTS
    
    #plotPotentials()
    #plotCurrents()

´´´
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i1` and `i2` are both rank-1, which is part of the problem, but they are also defined by formulae:

```py
i1 = -sigma*phi1.grad                                  # porous electrode matrix current, A/cm2
i2 = -kappa*phi2.grad                                  # porous electrode electrolyte current, A/cm2
```

which makes them unusable as solution variables.

Even if `i1` and `i2` were left as rank-1 `CellVariable`s, `ConvectionTerm` is not designed to work this way.

> ∇ ⋅ (− ∇1) + ∇ ⋅ (− ∇2) = 0 and ∇ ⋅ (− ∇1) = irxn

This is the correct approach for FiPy. I don't know what you tried, but I would write either:

```py
chargeConservationEq = (DiffusionTerm(coeff = -sigma, var = phi1) + DiffusionTerm(coeff = -kappa, var = phi2) == 0) 
matrixPotEq1 = (DiffusionTerm(coeff=-sigma, var = phi1) == irxn)
eq = (matrixPotEq1 & chargeConservationEq)
```

or

```py
matrixPotEq1 = (DiffusionTerm(coeff=-sigma, var = phi1) == irxn)
matrixPotEq2 = (DiffusionTerm(coeff=-kappa, var = phi2) == -irxn)
eq = (matrixPotEq1 & matrixPotEq2)
```

Either works and either conserves charge to machine precision.

**Notes:**

- `eq = (chargeConservationEq & matrixPotEq1)` (reversing the order of the first set of equations) does not work for me, at least with PETSc. I understand why, but I thought we had accounted for this.
- `phi2` must also be grounded: `phi2.constrain(0, where=mesh.facesLeft)`

---

**Edit:** Revised for revised final question

You are trying to apply six boundary conditions for two 2nd-order PDEs. This is over-constrained. Moreover, trying to set the value and the gradient at the same boundary amounts to a shooting method, which FiPy doesn't readily deal with.

If I change the boundary conditions to:

```py
phi1.constrain(0, where=mesh.facesRight)                                       # matrix potential grounded at x=L
phi2.constrain(0, where=mesh.facesLeft)                                       # electrolyte potential grounded at x=0
phi1.faceGrad.constrain([-cd/sigma.faceValue], where=mesh.facesLeft)         # matrix current at x=0
phi2.faceGrad.constrain([-cd/kappa.faceValue], where=mesh.facesRight)     # electrolyte current at x=L
```

then I get

[image: current vs position]

which makes some sort of sense.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. However setting phi2 to zero is not entirely physical as it implies there are no reactions at the boundary. Shouldn't phi2 be sufficiently constrained through its coupling to the other equation anyways, where there is a constraint on the value of phi1? No models in literature seem to have used phi2=0 at x=0 as a BC. Also, why is not the gradient of phi2 at x=0 zero as specified by the constraints?

Comment: phi2 is a potential; as such, its absolute value is completely arbitrary. Further, how does setting phi2 to be zero say anything about reactions at the boundary? i_rxn goes like the Laplacian of the potential, not like the value. Finally, please be explicit about what constraint on phi2 you think arises from constraining phi1. Use math.

Comment: I seem to have gotten a little bit ahead of myself when I commented earlier. I have edited my question with a new version of the code implementing your changes + with some more details.